# Trying to install older version of python package from pypi but pip says version not available

Tags: python, pip, pypi

I'm trying to install an older version of the `opencv-python` package, specifically [4.1.0.25](https://pypi.org/project/opencv-python/4.1.0.25/) but when running `pip install opencv-python==4.1.0.25` it complains that `Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement opencv-python==4.1.0.25`. The package clearly exists in pypi repo and it doesn't seem to be deprecated (except if I'm missing the flag). Is there a way to install it? Aren't all packages available in the pypi website available via `pip`?

Comment: What version of Python are you using? It looks like opencv-python 4.1.0.25 only supports up to Python version 3.7.

Comment: Interesting. I'm using 3.11.2, maybe that's why! Didn't know that repo versions were bound to the python version as well.

Comment: Yep, that'll be why. If you look at the available [files](https://pypi.org/project/opencv-python/4.1.0.25/#files) there's not one for 3.11. You could try installing from source https://github.com/opencv/opencv-python/tree/25 instead just in case it still works.